# Directory not empty error when deleting temp directory on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, directory, temp

I have code that

1. creates a temp directory
2. copies an EXE file there
3. runs the EXE and waits for exit
4. deletes the EXE file, and
5. deletes the temp directory.

On an Azure machine with slow HDD, we are seeing step (5) sometimes fail with the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.    
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound,    
WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)    
  at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
       ...
```

**What could cause this?** Are there cases where a process can have exited and released its hold on the exe file but somehow the OS still hangs on to the directory for a bit?

Here's what the code looks like:

```
// create the temp directory
var tempDirectoryName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectoryName);

// copy the exe
var exePath = Path.Combine(tempDirectoryName, "MyExe.exe")
using (var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(...))
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(exePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1024, useAsync: true))
{
    await resourceStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// run the exe and wait for exit (uses MedallionShell)
await Command.Run(exePath).Task.ConfigureAwait(false);

// cleanup
File.Delete(exePath); // this always succeeds
Directory.Delete(tempDirectory); // this sometimes fails, but only (that I've seen) on Azure
```

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the machine to see what (if anything) is in the temp directory when it fails to delete.

Comment: Can you check where your process is at that moment? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory or working directory? Maybe your process has not move out of the directory after running the MyExe.exe.  Might not even move into it to run, just a thought.

Comment: @JAZ I know that the current process does not switch directories to enter the temp directory, but not sure what else it might be doing (working from an error report)